# SlotSequence (##) form analogous to #[[ ;; n]]

Tags: syntax, core-language

I'm aware that this may be closed as offtopic but there are people around with "offtopic" knowledge :)

So, in `List` context we can: `#[[n ;; ]]` and `#[[ ;; n]]`, but we can't do this in context of `Sequence`. Only `##n` is available.

One may do

```
f[n_] := Unevaluated[##][[;; n]] &
f[2][1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> ```
> Sequence[1, 2]
> ```

but it is not what I'm looking for.

It is very often when I would like to use it. Of course there are no problems with workarounds. I'm just curious.

p.s. Syntax is an issue for sure, I thought something like `###2` could stand for this but `###` is automatically interpreted as `##1 #1`.

Comment: Just a note, `f[1][1]` won't work. Even more minor: `f[1][1, 2, 3]` gives `Sequence[1]`, whereas `##3 &[1, 2, 3]` gives 3. Oh well it would be nice to see an answer/"response" :).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom good points. :)

Comment: I think it could be connected to the reason there is `HoldFirst` and `HoldRest`, but no `HoldMost` and `HoldLast`. Obviously not quite the same, but perhaps related.

Answer (score 9):

How about something like:

```
seqChopper[seq_Sequence, span_Span] := Sequence @@ ((List@seq)[[span]])

SetAttributes[seqChopper, SequenceHold]

seqChopper[Sequence[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2 ;;]
seqChopper[Sequence[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2 ;; -2]
seqChopper[Sequence[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], -2 ;; 1 ;; -2]

(*
Sequence[2, 3, 4, 5]
Sequence[2, 3, 4]
Sequence[4, 2]
*)
```

Comment: `f[n_] := Unevaluated[##][[n]] &` will do too. What I'm interested in is rather "why" there is nothing built-in than w workaround. +1 for `SequenceHold` I've not seen it for a while.,