# How to write an operator that acts on pure function (to give another pure function)

Tags: function-construction, pure-function, operators

I would like to write an operator `oper` that acts on a pure function `f` with an undetermined number of arguments, with the syntax `oper[n][f]` to give another pure function, where `n` is an integer.  The point of this is to be able compose the operator like this:

```
oper[n2][oper[n1][f]]
```

The function `f` is a polynomial in all its arguments, and `oper[f]` will also be a polynomial.  Here is what `oper` is supposed to do for the case where $f$ takes three arguments:

$$\text{oper}[1][f](x,y,z) = [f(x,y,z)-f(0,y,z)]/x$$
$$\text{oper}[2][f](x,y,z) = [f(x,y,z)-f(x,0,z)]/y$$
$$\text{oper}[3][f](x,y,z) = [f(x,y,z)-f(x,y,0)]/z$$

It's supposed to take the difference of $f$ with itself but with the $n$th argument set to zero, and then divide the difference by the $n$th argument.

In general $f$ can have any number of arguments.
**Bonus:**  How about defining the composition like this: `oper[n1,n2,...][f]`, instead of `oper[`…`[oper[n2][oper[n1][f]]]`…`]`?

Comment: It would be better if you would edit this question to state your problem in _Mathematica_ code. The mixture of _Mathematica_ notation and traditional form you have posted makes it harder, not easier, to understand what you are requesting.

Comment: Why do you insist on pure functions? It seems to me that the operator you request should not have to distinquish between pure and ordinary functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one possibility:

```
oper[ns__] := 
 Fold[Function[{f, 
     n}, (f[##] - f @@ ReplacePart[{##},n -> 0])/Slot[n] &], #, {ns}] &
```

With this, you can do

```
oper[2,1][f][x,y,z]
```

> (-((-f[0, 0, z] + f[0, y, z])/y) + (-f[x, 0, z] + f[x, y, z])/y)/x

Note that even though `ns__` is a pattern (hence not totally "pure"), any operation `oper[n1,n2,...][f]` returns a pure function if `f` is pure.

Comment: This is what I wanted to do but didn't realize a construction like `{##} /. Slot[n] -> 0` would work! Is there a way to adapt this code so that it matches the OP's syntax (e.g. `oper[2][f]`)?

Comment: It looks like it. Just change it to `oper[n_]` and remove the `n` from the `Function` definition.

Comment: @march yes, but in that case it is no longer a "pure function" any longer. I'll add it to my answer anyway ;)

Comment: My interpretation is that he wanted to turn a pure function into a pure function and that `oper` didn't have to be pure.

Comment: @march Unfortunately it *does not* work.  Try for example `oper[2][f][x, x, x]` and note that *all* arguments are replaced with `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Mr.Wizard, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way to define `oper`:

```
oper[n_][f_] := (f[##] - Apply[f, {##}(1-UnitVector[Length@{##}, n])]) / {##}[[n]] &

oper[n1_, ns__][f_] := oper[n1][oper[ns][f]]
```

The first definition is the main one.  It generates the desired pure function for a given input function (which may or may not be pure itself):

```
oper[2][f]
(* (f[##1] - f @@ ({##1}*(1 - UnitVector[Length[{##1}], 2])))/{##1}[[2]] & *)
```

The generated pure function has the requested property that it can be applied to any number of arguments:

```
pf = oper[2][f];

pf[x, y, z]
(* (-f[x, 0, z] + f[x, y, z]) / y *)

pf[a, b, c, d]
(* (-f[a, 0, c, d] + f[a, b, c, d]) / b *)
```

The second `oper` definition implements the multiple-argument generalization, so that:

```
oper[3, 1, 2][f][x,y,z] === (oper[3]@oper[1]@oper[2]@f)[x,y,z]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

I propose:

```
oper[n_][fn_] := 
 Function[Null, (fn[##] - fn @@ ReplacePart[Hold[##], n -> 0])/Slot[n], HoldAll]

oper[2][f][x, y, z]
```

> ```
> (-f[x, 0, z] + f[x, y, z])/y
> ```

This also works on Functions that hold their arguments, e.g.:

```
foo = Function[Null, HoldForm[+##], HoldAll];

oper[1][foo][2 + 2, 1/0, Print[7]]
```

> ```
> (-(0+1/0+Print[7])+((2+2)+1/0+Print[7]))
> ```

Answer (score 4):

There is a closely related function [`DifferenceDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceDelta.html), which you could use as follows:

```
op[n_][f_] := 
 -DifferenceDelta[f[##], {#, 1, -#} &@{##}[[n]]]/{##}[[n]] &
```

Here is an example:

```
op[2][g][x, y, z]

(* ==> (-g[x, 0, z] + g[x, y, z])/y *)
```

The bonus question has already been answered by WReach, and I don't have anything shorter for that.

**Edit:**

I overlooked that the operation should use the function slots and not the arguments themselves. To extend the application of `DifferenceDelta` to this scenario, one could do this:

```
op[n_][f_] := -Module[{fn, i},
    DifferenceDelta[ReplacePart[fn[##], n -> i], {i, 1, -i}]/ i 
     /. {fn -> f, i -> Slot[n]}] &
```

Then the definition also works with examples like this, where the contents of the slots are arbitrary:

```
op[2][h][y, y^4, z^2]

(* ==> -((h[y, 0, z^2] - h[y, y^4, z^2])/y^4) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

On further thought and experimentation, neither the number of arguments nor the special definitions need be specified, since both `frontSlotSequence[0]` and `SlotSequence[n]` (when `n > (number of arguments of f)`) evaluate to `Sequence[]`. Therefore, this seems to work (although it is the least elegant of all the answers here, I think):

```
frontSlotSequence[n_] := Unevaluated[##][[;; n]] &

oper[n_] := With[{dec = n - 1, inc = n + 1}, 
  Function[f,
    (f[##] - f[frontSlotSequence[dec][##], 0, SlotSequence[inc]])/Slot[n] &
  ]
 ]
```

**Original post**

Here's a general answer, using the adapted `SlotSequence` from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44427/why-there-is-no-slotsequence-form-analogical-to-n).

We first define

```
frontSlotSequence[n_] := Unevaluated[##][[;; n]] &
```

which allows us to use all of the arguments to the function up to `n` along with `SlotSequence[n]` that allows us to use all the arguments *from* `n`.

If the number of arguments is `num = 5`, then define

```
Clear[num,oper]
num = 5;
oper[1] := Function[f, (f[##] - f[0, ##2])/Slot[1] &]
oper[n_ /; 1 < n < num] := With[{dec = n - 1, inc = n + 1}, 
  Function[f, (
    f[##] - f[frontSlotSequence[dec][##], 0, SlotSequence[inc]])/
    Slot[n] &]]
oper[num] := With[{num = num}, 
  Function[f, (f[##] - f[frontSlotSequence[num - 1][##], 0])/
    Slot[num] &]]
```

Then, for instance, the composition of `oper[1]` with `oper[2]` yields

```
oper[1][oper[2][f]][x,y,z]
(* f[0, 0, z]/(x y) - f[0, y, z]/(x y) - f[x, 0, z]/(x y) + f[x, y, z]/(x y) *)
```