# Access last variable in a pure function

Tags: pure-function

`#` is the first argument of a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html), `#n` the nth, `##` are all variables and `##n` all beginning with the nth variable.

Now, I would like to access the last argument. In a list, this would be `mylist[[-1]]`. Additionally, I would like to access all but the last argument which would be `Drop[mylist,-1]` for a list. Can this be achieved and if yes, how?

The reason for this is that I would like to pass all but the last argument to another function which can take different numbers of input arguments. Of course, I could change the order of the arguments, taking the last argument first, but this makes the arguments appear in a less logical order.

Example:

```
f1[a_:0,b_]:=a+b;
f2[a_:0,b_,c_]:=f1[a,b]*c
```

If I wanted to write `f2` as a pure function, how would I do this?

Comment: `f = {##}[[-1]] &`?

Comment: @Henrik that's too easy. Could have never thought of that! Thank you so much!

Comment: `f2 = With[{args = {##}}, f1 @@ Most[args] Last[args]] &`

Comment: @riddleculous why do you insist on a pure function? What about `f2[a_:0, b__,c_]:=f1[a,b]*c`, notice double `_` next to `b`, it stands for one or more arguments.

Comment: @Kuba I thought for my task it would be nice to have a pure function defined inline instead of an own formal function definition. The double-underscore trick is nice, of course. and it's good to have it as a reference here.

Comment: @riddleculous sure, whatever fits your needs. Btw, I just realized I asked once a closely related question: [Why there is no SlotSequence (##) form analogical to #\[\[ ;; n\]\]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44427/5478)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So, maybe `f = {##}[[-1]] &` is what you are looking for.

Comment: So the solution of the example would be `f2 = f1 @@ {##}[[;; -2]]*{##}[[-1]] &` resp. `f2 = f1 @@ Most[{##}]*Last[{##}] &`.

Answer (score 7):

Defining `f2` in terms of `f1` and `c` can be also obtained by using

```
f2 = With[{args = {##}}, f1 @@ Most[args] Last[args]] &
```

although, admittedly, using `Part` seems more natural.

Another way to achieve the same end is using patterns:

```
f2 = With[{args = {##}}, args /. {x__, y_} :> f1@x y] &
```

Although both definitions '*work*', they feel like '*workarounds*'; It would be really interesting to see a purely functional solution to this problem, if that is possible that is.